# Lasso tool: select only visible pixels

Tags: adobe-photoshop

Give a layer with some brush drawings, I want to use the lasso tool to select some parts of my drawing. However, I want the selection to only contain visible pixels. As it is now, the lasso tool's selection will contain the entire selection, regardless of there being transparent or visible pixels. Is this possible?

Look at this drawing: I have two layers. One is the background and another is the black circle.

[image]

Now I want to use the lasso tool to select this particular section of the circle:

[image]

But, as you can see, there are transparent pixels selected. What I want is something like this:

[image]

In other words, I want the selection area to only make use of pixels that are visible... **Using the lasso tool**.

---

Since you insist on asking me why I want to achieve this, it is because I have a drawing I want to shade using gradients on specific parts. For example, I want to shade half of the left leg of this character:

[image]

So I use the **lasso tool**. But if I apply the gradient, it will also fill the area outside her leg.

I am aware that I could make a mask of her body so that the gradient will not overflow outside her leg. However, given my workflow, it would be a lot more efficient and easy if I could just configure the lasso tool to only grab visible pixels. **This is the reason I want to achieve this: for efficiency/commodity.**

Photoshop CC 2014, Mac OSX.

Comment: How do you *know* transparent pixels are being selected? Because here.... they aren't. If you are doing a flood fill on the selection, that always ignores transparency.

Comment: Could you maybe explain a bit more about what you're trying to do?

Comment: @Joonas I've uploaded images better explaining what I want.

Comment: It's still a bit unclear to me why the transparent pixels would be a problem, as they are transparent. The selection in your example could be done by:  [First Ctrl or Cmd clicking the layer thumbnail to make a selection off of it and then using Rectangular marquee tool with Alt pressed down to contract the selection.](http://i.stack.imgur.com/pAgf9.gif). --- To get back to my confusion... [If you move, scale, cut the image, the transparent pixels are basically ignored.](http://i.stack.imgur.com/EfC1g.gif) Which is why I'm having hard time understanding why this would be an issue?

Comment: Let me guess.. you want to fill one half of the circle with a different color. When you make the selection you just flood fill and everything in the selection is filled. I think following the first link Joonas posted above solves this. You should make that an answer @Joonas

Comment: @Joonas Oh my god no, the half-a-circle thing was just an example. There, I've provided my very own current scenario and also updated the circle images.

Comment: I don't understand what is the problem here - my question is extremely clear: I want to use the lasso tool to select only visible pixels! I know my needs can be achieved using other methods such as a mask, but I want this because it would make my workflow much easier. But if it is not possible, *just say so please*.

Comment: The unclarity of the question comes from the fact that in most situations these transparent pixels in the selection are irrelevant. What you want to do with the selection is super important. See, if you'd want to fill it with color, the best method would probably be to just fill that selection as it is and Clipping mask that with the layer below. That way the edge stays perfect. If however you make that selection, where it follows the outer edge of the leg, and fill it with color you'd end up with some color leaking from below or at least some oddities...

Comment: So yea, to answer the question. I would totally clipping mask that. The reason is the one I commented on above. [Here's an example of that.](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eQiiD.gif) The first circle is where I do what you want to do and the second circle is where I use clipping mask. Example is in a gif format, so keep that in mind.

Answer (score 2):

Do this:

1. Make selection
2. Right click on layer thumbnail and choose **Intersect Transparency Mask**

[image]

**Image 1**: Animation of intersecting the selection with transparency mask

Comment: I know this is super old, but I love this idea. One question though. How do you add to this, once you select this option? For example, let's say you forgot to add a part of the image. If I go and try to select it, nothing happens. I have to go back, add it, then use this option. Why is that? Thank you.

Comment: @Apache save the selection you have.

Answer (score 0):

There are **many ways** to alter a layer with transparency without altering the transparency.....

Which one you use depends upon your desired result and workflow.

1. **Clipping Masks:**

   [image]
2. **<kbd>Command/Ctrl</kbd>-Clicking the layer thumbnail** to load it as a selection, then using a new layer:
   [image]
   This method only selects the non-transparent pixels.
3. **A layer mask** on a new layer:
   [image]
4. **Layer Styles**:
   [image]

I think the *least* efficient way is #2 -- using selections.

Also be aware if you create a selection which contains transparent areas copying, duplicating, transforming, etc all *ignore* the transparent pixels. It is only when you attempt to *fill* a selection that any transparency may be covered depending upon your selection method.

Answer (score 0):

So I stumbled upon this post with the same exact question, and I figured out another way while trying the other answers.

Here's what you do:

1. Make your selection any way you want; marquee, lasso, whatever.
2. Switch to the move tool (v)
3. Move your selection with the arrow keys any direction.

Your selection will refine to exclude transparent pixels! Yay!